# Two click listeners

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, textview, listviewitem

I have a List view.Here what I did is the 3 level expandable listview using a **[tutorial](http://twocentscode.blogspot.in/2014/02/three-level-expandable-listview.html?)**.In that list view can I put a click listener on text view and item of the list view?
my mainActivity

```
public drawerlist(final Context context, final LayoutInflater inflater, ListView listView1){
            this.listView=listView1;
            lists = new ArrayList<NLevelItem>();
            requestQueue1= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://www.ezybzy.com/cntrldata/ezproductfristcategory.php",
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                //list = new ArrayList<Group>();

                                ja = response.getJSONArray("hi");

                                ja2 = response.getJSONArray("hi2");

                                ja3 = response.getJSONArray("hi3");
                                firsttitle = new String[ja.length()];
                                firstcatid = new int[ja.length()];
                                JSONObject jsonObject2 = null, jsonObject3 = null, jsonObject;
                                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                    jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);


                                // Log.e("hie",jsonObject2.getInt("second_category_id")+"");
                                //jsonObject3 = ja3.getJSONObject(i);
                                firstcatid[i] = jsonObject.getInt("first_category_id");
                                firsttitle[i] = jsonObject.getString("first_category_name");
                            }
                            secondcatid = new int[ja2.length()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja2.length(); i++) {
                                jsonObject2 = ja2.getJSONObject(i);
                                secondcatid[i] = jsonObject2.getInt("second_category_id");
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                final NLevelItem grandParent = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(firsttitle[i],firstcatid[i]+""), null, new NLevelView() {

                                    @Override
                                    public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                        final ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                                        if (item.isExpanded()) {
                                            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_minus);
                                            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                        } else iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add);

                                        String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                        tv.setText(name);
                                        return view;
                                    }
                                });
                                lists.add(grandParent);
                                //int numChildren = rng.nextInt(4) + 1;
                                for (int j = 0; j < ja2.length(); j++) {
                                    jsonObject2 = ja2.getJSONObject(j);

                                    if (firstcatid[i] == jsonObject2.getInt("first_category_id")) {

                                        parent = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(jsonObject2.getString("second_category_name"),jsonObject2.getInt("second_category_id")+""), grandParent, new NLevelView() {

                                            @Override
                                            public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                                final ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                                                if (item.isExpanded()) {
                                                    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_minus);
                                                    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                                } else iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add);
                                                tv.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
                                                String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                                tv.setText(name);
                                                return view;
                                            }
                                        });

                                        lists.add(parent);                                // int grandChildren = rng.nextInt(5) + 1;
                                    for (int k = 0; k < ja3.length(); k++) {
                                        jsonObject3 = ja3.getJSONObject(k);
                                        if (secondcatid[j] == jsonObject3.getInt("second_category_id")) {
                                            NLevelItem child = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(jsonObject3.getString("third_category_name"),jsonObject3.getString("third_category_id")+""), parent, new NLevelView() {

                                                @Override
                                                public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                                    //tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                                    tv.setPadding(40,0,0,0);
                                                    String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                                    tv.setText(name);
                                                    return view;
                                                }
                                            });

                                            lists.add(child);} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            final NLevelAdapter adapter = new NLevelAdapter(lists);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                                        long arg3) {
                                    ((NLevelAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).toggle(arg2);
                                    ((NLevelAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter();
                                    NLevelItem item2 = (NLevelItem)adapter.getItem(arg2);

                                    id = ((SomeObject)item2.getWrappedObject()).getId();


                                    Toast.makeText(context, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    try {

                                        for (int i = 0; i < ja3.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = ja3.getJSONObject(i);
                                            if (id.equals(jsonObject1.getString("third_category_id"))){
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categorypage.class);
                                                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }catch (Exception e){

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue1.add(jsonObjectRequest);



    }

    class SomeObject {
        public String name;
        public String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public SomeObject(String name,String id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id=id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

In this I want to put on click listener to the text view and the list item.You can refer this **[tutorial](http://twocentscode.blogspot.in/2014/02/three-level-expandable-listview.html?)**.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What issue are you having?

Comment: I want to put one click listener to the text view of the list view and another to the item of the listview

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a click listener to it? Your code shows you adding an click listener to the list, but not the textview.

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         //on click code to execute....
     }
 });
```

Comment: but it is not working when adding below the listview.OnitemClickListener.

Comment: @KBJ Please show me the code of what you have tried, and how do you determine it to be not working? It might be very small area of click to click on the textview, depending on your design?